# Where have profile views figures gone, and why?

Tags: discussion

The number of profile views that a member had used to be given on a members profile page. Has this information now just disappeared? If so, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Courtesy of Meta. The change was announced in August 2021:
[Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive)

> Dropped the profile views metric entirely. It’s a vanity metric and we don’t think it’s worth keeping around.

The statistic was abandoned as it was seen as vanity feature, adding no value to the profile page (developer/staff view). Please note the current 441 downvotes versus the 42 upvotes.

Comment: The last time I checked, it was available on the [defunct iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368338/323179).

Comment: @Laurel maybe that's the reason for Araucaria noticing the change only recently.

Comment: Why should a user, who is not here anymore, worry about profile views? Who knows!!

Comment: @Gio  It's a tangible way for any one of us to see how many visitors and users visit our profile to get an idea of the person behind the questions and/or answers posted. Besides, we know Araucaria is still *here*,  and I am hopeful he will actively contribute  and rely less on community wiki posts.